# iphone google maps and waypoints

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have a number of waypoints stored in my app database, how would I pass these to the MapView in my app ?

If anyone can point me in the direction of a tutorial or some sample code would be great.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView